# Monit - monitor tinc VPN

Tags: monit

Is there any way to monitor a tinc VPN with a monit network check?

The following check does not see if the vpn connection is actually established (means if there is a connection to one of the vpn servers)

```
CHECK NETWORK vpn with INTERFACE mynetwork
IF FAILED LINK
THEN RESTART
```

What I do now is checking for one host in my vpn:

```
CHECK HOST myhost with ADDRESS 10.8.1.111
    IF FAILED ICMP TYPE ECHO
    THEN restart
```

Which is fine so far but does not cover the situation that this specific host is down while others are up.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem, and my solution was this:

```
cat /etc/monit/conf.d/tinc

# monitor tinc daemon
check process tinc with pidfile /var/run/tinc.net.pid
  group system
  start program = "/usr/sbin/service tinc start"
  stop program  = "/usr/sbin/service tinc stop"
  if failed host 127.0.0.1 port 655 type udp then restart
```